# spring-cloud-bus-kafka create applciationcontext twice

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-bus

cloud version is Brixton.SR1....

i use sping-cloud-bus-kafka and sping-cloud-zookeeper-all (using zookeeper to discovery) ,every time ,there are two items in zookeeper,as :

**zookeeper data : 
[zookeeper data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F362P.png)**

**my yml is:
[my yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNxp7.png)**

when started, it create applicationcontext twice , kafka producer twice, zookeeperclient twice, the stack trace is:

**first time:**

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 765 in ZooKeeper))     
ZooKeeper.create(String, byte[], List<ACL>, CreateMode) line: 765   
CreateBuilderImpl$11.call() line: 721   
CreateBuilderImpl$11.call() line: 704   
RetryLoop.callWithRetry(CuratorZookeeperClient, Callable<T>) line: 108  
CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(String, byte[]) line: 701    
CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(String, byte[]) line: 477   
CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(String, byte[]) line: 467 
CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(String, byte[]) line: 44  
ServiceDiscoveryImpl<T>.internalRegisterService(ServiceInstance<T>) line: 224   
ServiceDiscoveryImpl<T>.reRegisterServices() line: 444  
ServiceDiscoveryImpl<T>.start() line: 131   
ZookeeperLifecycle.register() line: 55  
ZookeeperLifecycle(AbstractDiscoveryLifecycle).start() line: 102    
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(Map<String,Lifecycle>, String, boolean) line: 173 
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor, Map, String, boolean) line: 51  
DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start() line: 346  
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(boolean) line: 149 
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh() line: 112 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).finishRefresh() line: 852    
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 541  
SpringApplication.refresh(ApplicationContext) line: 766 
SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplicationRunListeners, ApplicationArguments) line: 361    
SpringApplication.run(String...) line: 307  
SpringApplicationBuilder.run(String...) line: 134   
BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(ConfigurableEnvironment, SpringApplication) line: 140  
BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) line: 84   
BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent) line: 62  
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(ApplicationListener, ApplicationEvent) line: 166   
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent, ResolvableType) line: 138    
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent) line: 121    
EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(SpringApplicationEvent) line: 111   
EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(ConfigurableEnvironment) line: 65    
SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(ConfigurableEnvironment) line: 54 
SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplicationRunListeners, ApplicationArguments) line: 330    
SpringApplication.run(String...) line: 307  
BaseApplication.main(String[]) line: 42 
Hello.main(String[]) line: 15
```

**second time :**

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 765 in ZooKeeper)) 
ZooKeeper.create(String, byte[], List<ACL>, CreateMode) line: 765   
CreateBuilderImpl$11.call() line: 721   
CreateBuilderImpl$11.call() line: 704   
RetryLoop.callWithRetry(CuratorZookeeperClient, Callable<T>) line: 108  
CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(String, byte[]) line: 701    
CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(String, byte[]) line: 477   
CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(String, byte[]) line: 467 
CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(String, byte[]) line: 44  
ServiceDiscoveryImpl<T>.internalRegisterService(ServiceInstance<T>) line: 224   
ServiceDiscoveryImpl<T>.reRegisterServices() line: 444  
ServiceDiscoveryImpl<T>.start() line: 131   
ZookeeperLifecycle.register() line: 55  
ZookeeperLifecycle(AbstractDiscoveryLifecycle).start() line: 102    
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(Map<String,Lifecycle>, String, boolean) line: 173 
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor, Map, String, boolean) line: 51  
DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start() line: 346  
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(boolean) line: 149 
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh() line: 112 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).finishRefresh() line: 852    
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 541  
SpringApplication.refresh(ApplicationContext) line: 766 
SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplicationRunListeners, ApplicationArguments) line: 361    
SpringApplication.run(String...) line: 307  
SpringApplicationBuilder.run(String...) line: 134   
BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(ConfigurableEnvironment, SpringApplication) line: 140  
BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) line: 84   
BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent) line: 62  
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(ApplicationListener, ApplicationEvent) line: 166   
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent, ResolvableType) line: 138    
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent) line: 121    
EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(SpringApplicationEvent) line: 111   
EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(ConfigurableEnvironment) line: 65    
SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(ConfigurableEnvironment) line: 54 
SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplicationRunListeners, ApplicationArguments) line: 330    
SpringApplication.run(String...) line: 307  
SpringApplicationBuilder.run(String...) line: 134   
DefaultBinderFactory<T>.getBinder(String) line: 156 
ChannelBindingService.getBinderForChannel(String) line: 142 
ChannelBindingService.bindProducer(MessageChannel, String) line: 104    
BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(ChannelBindingService) line: 205   
OutputBindingLifecycle.start() line: 57 
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(Map<String,Lifecycle>, String, boolean) line: 173 
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor, Map, String, boolean) line: 51  
DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start() line: 346  
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(boolean) line: 149 
DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh() line: 112 
AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).finishRefresh() line: 852 
AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext).finishRefresh() line: 140  
AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 541   
AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext).refresh() line: 118    
SpringApplication.refresh(ApplicationContext) line: 766 
SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplicationRunListeners, ApplicationArguments) line: 361    
SpringApplication.run(String...) line: 307  
BaseApplication.main(String[]) line: 42 
Hello.main(String[]) line: 15
```

who knows what happens????

thanks.....

Comment: Need more information, maybe pom or a project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/bloodstars/spring-cloud-config-git

Comment: in cloudproject.zip,   there is a sample-web project, can reproduces the problem....

Comment: DefaultBinderFactory<T>.getBinder(String) line: 156      create another ConfigurableApplicationContext